# integrate $\int \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x^2-2x-5}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

> $$\int \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x^2-2x-5}$$

I can see where t start, maybe $$\int \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x^2-2x-5}=\int \frac{6x-2}{3x^2-2x-5}+\frac{x^2-5x+3}{3x^2-2x-5}=\ln|3x^2-2x-5|+\int \frac{x^2-5x+3}{3x^2-2x-5}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Long division:

$$\frac{49}{24}\int\frac{dx}{3x-5}-\frac 1 8 \int \frac{dx}{x+1}+\frac 1 3 \int 1dx=\dots$$

Comment: How did you get to those denominator?

Comment: @gbox  $3x^2-2x-5=(x+1)(3x-5)$

Comment: after long division I get $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{5x+8}{3(3x^2-2x-5}$

Comment: @gbox this is corrent but you didn't finished, note that $\frac{5x+8}{3(3x^2-2x-5)}=\frac{5x+8}{3(x+1)(3x-5)}=\frac{A}{3(x+1)}+\frac{B}{3(3x-5)}=\dots$